# StarUML ER diagram with relation with 3 entities

Tags: entity-relationship

I'm using StarUML in order to do a ER diagram and I can create relation with two entities like this:

[image: relation with two entity]

and in StarUML:

[image: in StarUML]

But I cannot create a relation with 3 entity like this:

[image: relation with 3 entities]

Have you some ideas to do it in StarUML?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the StarUML supports only the physical ER diagram symbols and you need to represent your database structure using a physical ER translation.

[image: I found this example]

you can also find some reference here
https://www.lucidchart.com/pages/ER-diagram-symbols-and-meaning